# Before they could stop him, he…

Tags: grammar

He ran out of the room before they could stop him.

Before they could stop him, he ran out of the room.

My friend told me the second sentence is mistaken, why?

In my eyes, they are the same.

Comment: They are both correct, and mean the same thing.

Comment: As Peter says, your friend is mistaken.